# How to import an extended public key into bitcoin core 0.16

Tags: bitcoin-core, public-key, import, xpub

I exported an xpub key from a HW wallet and want to import it into my own node to keep track of changes to the balance. My node is running satoshi 0.16.1

Can someone help me find the right syntax for bitcoin-cli, or make a statement about whether it is possible at all to import extended public keys?

Edit: @aantonop seems to state in this video (https://youtu.be/8mpDcBfNA7g) @ 16:55 that this is possible in bitcoin core though I may be getting it wrong and also he isn't omniscient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible in bitcoin core right now. You can use electrum and import your xpub as a watch-only wallet.