# can I run bitcoin core with public key only

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, public-key

I'm looking a way for secure setup of web site that accepts bitcoin payments. Ideally I'd like to create wallet off-site and be able to deploy bitcoin core online with public key only that I believe should be enough to generate new addresses and watch for incoming payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **can I run bitcoin core with public key only**

That would be a watch-only wallet - usually achieved by importing an externally derived address.

> **deploy bitcoin core online with public key only that I believe should be enough to generate new addresses**

In principle you can derive addresses from a public key but, as far as I know, Bitcoin core doesn't provide any way to import a public key and derive addresses from it. But I haven't tried.

See

- [How to import an extended public key into bitcoin core 0.16](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/77564/13866)
- https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/importpubkey/

You could always generate addresses from a public key externally and *then* use the Bitcoin core API to import those addresses. There are many Bitcoin libraries for popular programming languages.

- [How bitcoin addresses are generated?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50289/13866)
- https://godoc.org/github.com/btcsuite/btcutil#NewAddressPubKey